# Grouping 2 categorical variables with geom_boxplot

Tags: r, variables, grouping, boxplot, categorical-data

I have tried some examples I found here but I always get an error or a different graph from what I need (e.g. lines instead of the boxplot, or only 2 boxes instead of 4).

I want to plot the following

````
Condition       Time       mean           sem
  A                I            0.5578552     0.05294356
  A                II           0.6957565     0.09149457
  P                I            0.7078374     0.08142464
  P                II           0.7762761      0.10945771 ```
````

I need "Condition" in the x axis and I need to group "Time".
The idea is to get a similar visual representation to this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY3si.png)

My attempt was:

````
ggplot(data = means.sem, aes(x = Condition, y = mean, fill=Time, ymin = mean-sem, ymax = mean + sem)) 
+ geom_boxplot() +   
stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.5)+   
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 0.85))+   scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "grey"))+  
 labs(y= "Mean", x="")+   theme_classic()```
````

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What do you want your y-axis to be? On the assumption it is, for example, the sem variable, I use the following code:

```
boxplot <- ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=condition, y=sem, fill=time)) + geom_boxplot(position="dodge2")
```

Obviously you can alter the colours, etc as you need to.

EDIT: changed the position to dodge2 as this creates a pleasing small gap between each boxplot within a group.

Comment: Thank you William! Sorry, poor explanation, but you got it, "Condition" as y-axis. "Mean" as x-axis, and the groups are "Time". But, I still get only "lines", not the plots. I thought maybe I need to have "ymin = mean-sem, ymax = mean + sem" for the plots, but still did not work, What am I missing here? Thank you for your help, I spent hours on this!

Comment: Can you post your code that is producing these “lines” rather than the box plots please?

Comment: Yes of course! I added to my question, to be easier to read. I guess, the plot is assuming single values to each plot, once I add "Time" as fill, right? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I tried with the entire data set (not just means and sd) and I got the plots. However, I also received the following message "Warning message:
Removed 70 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot)."